# Azure DevOps: Adding team members to a new team/area

Tags: azure-devops

I have created a new Team/Area under our project within Azure DevOps.
When I send the URL for the backlog, the team members are able to access the link but not see any of the work items.

I have tried the following:

1. Confirm the user has Basic licence.
2. Confirm the user has access to the project.
3. Added the user to the Team for that area.

Is there anything obvious I am missing?

I am pretty confident this is not a bug, but just something in the process of giving users access that I am not doing.

Any help very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Alasdair.

Comment: What do you mean by "send the URL for the backlog, the team members are able to access the link"? Do you mean the team members can visit the Azure DevOps Service Boards Backlogs? And they can not see any workitems in the Backlogs? If so, please make sure your team members [choose the right team in the Backlogs page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2s0L.png). And also check the `Project Settings`-`Team configuration`-`Areas`, make sure [the target Team area has been added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ8p4.png).

Comment: Hi Yang, thanks so much for the detailed reply.  To clarify, yes, I am sharing a URL of the team/area backlog.  And users are unable to see the work items.  The user is selecting the team on the backlog page, and I have checked the project settings which also match the example links you have shown.  The only way I seem to be able to get the user to view the work items is to add them to the Project Administrators group.  Any other settings I should check?  Many Thanks, Alasdair.

p.s. I have a screenshot of the settings, but not sure how to add it into a comment.

Comment: Please check the difference of "Permissions" of "Project Administrators" and your team at `Project Settings` - `Permissions`, basically, set all permissions of your team to `Allow`. About how to add an img in comment, you can only link it in the comment in fact like i did in my comment. [Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk9tf.gif).

Comment: Thanks Yang!  That's it, the team did not have 'Allow' permissions.  I've set them now and it's all working.  Is this something that I need to set every time I create a new team?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have gathered my comments into the answer below. You can accept it and if you have further quesions, please add comment to that answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> When I send the URL for the backlog, the team members are able to access the link but not see any of the work items.

This could be caused by multiple reasons which means we might need to check several setttings.

1. Choose the right team in BackLogs page:

[image]

2. check the `Project Settings`-`Team configuration`-`Areas`, make sure the target Team area has been added:

[image]

3. Check `Project Settings` - `Permissions` and make sure your team has
   the right permission to see the BackLogs Itmes.

   > Is this something that I need to set every time I create a new team?

   No, you don't have to set them every time. When you create a team,
   the `Permissions` setting could be automatically inherited:

   [image]